# Суммирование в диапазоне при нескольких условиях (формула)

Tags: excel, open-office

Как к этой формуле добавить еще одно условие ?

**=SUMPRODUCT(G4:G20="DONE"; E4:E20)**

Эта формула слаживает суммы в **E4:E20** только там где в **G4:G20** колонках будет слово **DONE**

Как добавить еще одно условие ? по типу DONE ?  к примеру суммировать если **G4:G20 = "DONE"** и **F4:F20 = "ALEX"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для одного условия не нужно использовать тяжелую *СУММПРОИЗВ*

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(G4:G20;"DONE";E4:E20)
```

Два условия эта функция не потянет, но есть младшая сестричка:

```
=СУММЕСЛИМН(E4:E20;G4:G20;"DONE";F4:F20;"ALEX")
```

Или уже испробованная функция:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(--(G4:G20="DONE");--(F4:F20="ALEX");E4:E20)
```

Для разнообразия - формула массива (вводится тремя клавишами *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*)

```
=СУММ(ЕСЛИ(G4:G20="DONE";ЕСЛИ(F4:F20="ALEX";E4:E20)))
```

*Нелокализованные: SUMIF, SUMIFS, SUMPRODUCT, SUM, IF*

Comment: SUMIFS - эта работает.

Comment: Да все они работают. Но в *Excel*. Для *Calc*, возможно, нужно немного подправить. Не заблуждайтесь: *OpenOffice Excel*  - нет такого

Comment: А как использовать NOT ? к примеру если DONE и не ALEX ?

Comment: =СУММЕСЛИМН(E4:E20;G4:G20;"DONE";F4:F20;"<>ALEX")

Comment: Где почтитать о последовательности логики в формулах ? т.е по какой схеме они строятся ?

Comment: В справке по функциям. А логика формул строится по алгоритму задачи. Что и как применять - справка, сеть, форумы... в общем, опыт приобретается на практических здачах

Comment: Понял, вопрос =СУММЕСЛИМН(E4:E20;G4:G20;"DONE";F4:F20;"<>ALEX"),  к примеру как этой формуле добавить не ALEX и не ROBIN ? т.е по двум критериям

Comment: а подумать? ) У Вас уже есть и как учитывать, и как не учитывать. Добавьте условие)

Comment: Сделал, я просто понял синтакс :) теперь надеюсь будет проще